# can't get rid of top and bottom drop shadows

Tags: html, css, dropshadow, drop-shadow

Why with the following code, I still can't get rid of drop shadows at the top and bottom. Although the drop shadows are "small", yet still they are there.

```
div#inner_container {
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 box-shadow:0 9px 0 0 transparent,
            0 -9px 0 0 transparent,
            12px 0 15px -4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5),
           -12px 0 15px -4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 position: relative;
 z-index: 5000;
}
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code?  I added what you have to jsfiddle, but can't see the drop-shadow that you're talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/9eJnG/

Comment: @ews2001: Strange. When looking at you fiddle, it dont happen, but here "http://www.pufs.org/test/cattle.html" it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
box-shadow: 10px 0px 12px -5px #ffffff, -10px 0px 12px -5px #ffffff;
```

Comment: tried that. But on live site, it still has some small shadow at top and bottom. Is box-shadow inherited?

Answer (score 1):

It's not that there's a drop shadow on top, but that you set the spread so high it's bleeding to a point where you can see it:

```
box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0px transparent,
            0 0px 0px 0px transparent,
            12px 0 9px -10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5),
            -12px 0 9px -10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
```

Try this. I'm sure this can be further simplified, though. It looks unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 1):

You can add top and bottom shadow which is the background color that will be placed on top of the bleeding shadow:

```
box-shadow:
0 -5px 0px 0 black,
0 5px 0px 0 black,            
12px 0 15px -4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5),
-12px 0 15px -4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
```

Or you can use `:before`, `:after` ([CSS Drop Shadow](http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/))

Both examples: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEkwJ